# Inserting date in PHP prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert current date (in d-m-Y) in a prepared statement into mysql table. I can't get the code right.
I am calling current date in php by

```
$dat = date("d-m-Y");
```

and then including in a prepared statement like this

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (name, date) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $name, $dat);
$reslt = $stmt->execute();
```

In the table, the date does not get inserted. It remains 0000-00-00. How can I rectify this?

Comment: mysql always support `YYYY-MM-DD` format by default. So you need to convert your date format to `$dat = date('Y-m-d');`

Comment: `$dat = date("Y-m-d");`

Comment: which datatype you have used in mysql?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use the YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
$dat = date("Y-m-d");
```